# 2nd back file created when using vim in centos

Tags: linux, vim, centos

When i create files in centos 6.6, A 2nd file for each one I create is created by the os or something (not sure what creates it),  how can i disable this?

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group  231 Feb 11 13:00 adminList.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 1090 Feb 11 13:00 adminList.php~
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group  560 Feb 11 13:00 clientList.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group  900 Feb 11 13:00 clientList.php~
```

I only wrote 2 of these files. The ~ files were automatically created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is vim creating backup files.

See `:h 'backup` and `:h 'backupext` (and all the other backup related settings in between those two).